# ng-grid Data overlapping

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ng-grid

I am new to AngularJS and trying to get data in a grid using ng-grid. I am able to get the data but it is overlapping on each other and I cannot see any Grid. Only one box is coming. I tried using ng-style, ui-grid.css and ng-grid.css but I think that the styling is not working properly. I cannot share the full code but I have added some snippets below.
What am I doing wrong?

my js file:

```
  $scope.myGrid={data:'roles',
        columnDefs: [
{field: 'roleId', displayName: 'Role Id'},
{field:'roleName', displayName:'Role Name'},
{field:'roleDesc', displayName:'Description'}
]};
```

my html page:

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="myGrid"></div>
```

scripts added:

```
<script src="/angular.js"/>
<script src="/jquery-1.12.4.js"/>
<script src="/ng-grid.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I finally used ui-grid to solve my issue but I would really like to know what was wrong with this code.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are not using ng-grid style sheets  I overcome the same problem by using ng-grid style sheets

```
   I hope this will help you
```